# DateTime converision to date In Dotnet MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I need to Convert DateTime field to Date in my model
my view part is this

```
<input class="input_width02 text-box single-line" id="PrdExpiry_@row" name="PrdExpiry[@row]" type="date" autocomplete="off" onchange="productExpDate(@row)" style="width:110px" value="@Model.itemDetails[i].Prd_ExpDateFormat">
```

And my model is

```
 public Nullable<System.DateTime> Prd_ExpDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Foe nullable properties, you need to check the value first.

```
if(Prd_ExpDate.HasValue)
{
    var shortDate = Prd_ExpDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```